# fatal error: subscript: subRange extends past String end Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am building an application which incorporates the use of both firebase and parse,and for some reason i keep getting the fatal error: `fatal error: subscript: subRange extends past String end`

Not sure why i keep getting this ;/

I tried doing a search and found nothing. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's kinda similar to "Array index out of range", but for Strings.

```
let str = "qwertyui"
var str1 = "qwer" // length = 4
let ind = advance(str.startIndex, 6) //equals 6
str1[ind] //fatal error: subscript: subRange extends past String end
str1.removeAtIndex(ind) //fatal error: subscript: subRange extends past String end
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous thread causes this problem may occur.

Instead of using `DespatchQueue.main.async{}`, use `DespatchQueue.main.sync{}`.